# How can I determine whether a column exists in a SQL Server CE table with C#?

Tags: c#, sql, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

The legacy code does it this way:

```
public bool isValidField(string tableName, string fieldName)
{
    bool retVal;
    string tblQuery = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", fieldName, tableName);
    checkConnection();
    try
    {
        SqlCeCommand cmd = objCon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = tblQuery;
        object objvalid = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        retVal = (null != objvalid);
    }
    catch
    {
        retVal = false; 
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

...but I find it doesn't always work. After calling that method, and getting `false`, some code ALTERS the table to add some columns, but I'm getting:

> A column ID occurred more than once in the specification.

I found here on StackOverflow a couple of promising SQL statements:

```
if exists(select * from sys.columns 
        where Name = N'columnName' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tableName'))
```

and

```
IF COL_LENGTH('table_name','column_name') IS NULL
```

...but am not sure how to implement this in C# / .NET 1.1

Do I need to use ExecuteScalar and cast the returned value to a bool? Or something else?

### UPDATE

Changing it to this didn't rectify matters:

```
public bool isValidField(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    bool retVal;
    string tblQuery = string.Format(
        "COL_LENGTH({0},{1}) IS NULL",
        tableName,
        columnName);

    checkConnection();
    try
    {
        SqlCeCommand cmd = objCon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = tblQuery;
        object objvalid = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        retVal = Convert.ToBoolean(objvalid);
    }
    catch
    {
        retVal = false; 
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Oddly enough, I see even more of those error messages with the new code.

### UPDATE 3

It made no difference when I altered the code this way:

```
string tblQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS"
                  + " WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME"
                  + " = @columnName";

checkConnection();
try
{
    SqlCeCommand cmd = objCon.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = tblQuery;
    SqlCeParameter tblNameParam = new SqlCeParameter(
        "@tableName",
        SqlDbType.NVarChar,
        128);

    tblNameParam.Value = tableName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(tblNameParam);
    SqlCeParameter colNameParam = new SqlCeParameter(
        "@columnName",
        SqlDbType.NVarChar,
        128);

    colNameParam.Value = tableName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(colNameParam);
    int i = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    retVal = i > 0;
}
```

...so I don't know which way is preferable; this does seem more straightforward to me...any thoughts, anyone?

Comment: *** SQL Injection Alert ***

Comment: That depends on how isValidField() is called - how the vals for the args are acquired, doesn't it?

Comment: There is a GetSchema method that could give you any details on your table schema, but, if I remember correctly it is available startin from Framework 2.0

Comment: @Steve: "Dang it!!!" <-- Kip Dynamite

Comment: @ClayShannon - Yes and no. It's more proper to create `SqlParameters` to ensure the data isn't tampered with.

Comment: @Scott: Agreed/geschenckt. I could use the excuse that I'm not at the "gingerbread"/finish carpentry part yet, but...there's no time like the present.

Comment: @ClayShannon - LoL .. exactly

Comment: [Check this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kcax58fh(v=vs.71).aspx), you need to test with SqlCeConnection, but probably it will work also for that

Comment: @Steve: Ah yes, that's right; this (string.Format) is the only way I know of to do this sort of thing (dynamically building DDL and certain types of queries).

Comment: @Steve - I was referring to SQL Injection in the command text.

Comment: @Scott: but what is being replaced by the string.Format() are a column name and a table name - those can't be parameterized in the normal way, so...what would be the alternate and more secure way to do it?

Comment: @ClayShannon - Maybe this can help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651582/sanitize-table-column-name-in-dynamic-sql-in-net-prevent-sql-injection-attack

Comment: @Scott: I'm still not seeing any parameterization of vals other than constructs such as "...WHERE Bla = @Blah" If this really is available, it is either something new or something vendor-specific.

Comment: @ClayShannon - Right, when I wrote the SqlParameter comment, I hadn't totally looked over your exact query to notice you didn't have a WHERE clause. I understand what you are saying, but still any ad-hoc query is subject to SQL injection.  For example, I could just assign `"1; DROP DA" + "TABASE database_name; --"` to `tableName`, could I not? That's all I'm talking about. *(concatenation due to SO not letting me post without)*

Comment: @Scott: Theoretically, I guess, but how a user cold actually insert/inject that value, in this case, anyway, I'm not seeing.

Comment: @ClayShannon - How your code is used is unknown to us, as we just see your method.  So how you get the value for `tableName`, I don't know. In any case, it doesn't have to be a "user", it could be a "malicious developer" who inserts some code that calls that method, who knows? I'm just saying it's possible in this scenario.

Comment: @Scott: If you count malicious developers as threats, you may as well just throw up your hands. Of course a developer can wreak all kinds of havoc if he has access to the code base. At some point you have to stop looking over your shoulder and stop sweating bullets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just query the [information schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174156.aspx) tables to get the information you want:

```
public bool isValidField(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    var tblQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS"
                   + " WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND"
                   + " COLUMN_NAME = @columnName";

    SqlCeCommand cmd = objCon.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = tblQuery;
    var tblNameParam = new SqlCeParameter(
        "@tableName",
        SqlDbType.NVarChar,
        128);

    tblNameParam.Value = tableName
    cmd.Parameters.Add(tblNameParam);
    var colNameParam = new SqlCeParameter(
        "@columnName",
        SqlDbType.NVarChar,
        128);

    colNameParam.Value = columnName
    cmd.Parameters.Add(colNameParam);
    object objvalid = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // will return 1 or null
    return objvalid != null;
}
```

Comment: This code looks way cleaner than the legacy code, but for whatever reason, it causes the app to simply flash exceedingly short-lived dialogs to the screen (the app proper never opens). I changed the isValidField() method back to the legacy (crazy looking code) - the only change - and it's back to what passes for normal. Strange...

Comment: @ClayShannon I dropped the call to `checkConnection()`. Not sure if that's necessary, and I also took the `try-catch` blocks out to simplify the code and because it's generally *bad practice* to catch every exception. The main thrust of my answer was just to present a different way of querying the database, so you may need to adapt the code back for your project.

Comment: With a hybrid of the two, I got it to run, but I'm still getting the err msgs, so I'll have to look over my code more closely tomorrow.

Comment: Would "SELECT COUNT(*)..." work as well? It would seem more straightforward, if so...

Answer (score 2):

```
    public bool IsValidField(SqlCeConnection objCon, string tableName, string columnName)
    {
        const string query = "SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS"
                                + " WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLENAME AND"
                                + " COLUMN_NAME = @COLUMNNAME";

        using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, objCon))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TABLENAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = tableName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@COLUMNNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = columnName;
            var objvalid = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // will return 1 or null
            return objvalid != null;
        }
    }
```