# Why isn't my sql command accepting a quoted identifier for a table name?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, quoted-identifier

I wanted to make my sql query *bullet proof* and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651582/sanitize-table-column-name-in-dynamic-sql-in-net-prevent-sql-injection-attack) question about sanitizing table/column names.

I followed the advices but somehow it doesn't work as expected.

My table name is `foo.Bar` so I passed it to the `CommandBuilder`'s `QuoteIdentifier` method and it gave me `[foo.Bar]` back.

When I call `(string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` it complains that this table doesn't exist. So I tried to initially define the table name as `[foo].[Bar]`. In this case `QuoteIdentifier` creates `[[foo]].[Bar]]]` which also doesn't work.

The only thing that works is when I specify just `[foo].[Bar]` without using the `QuoteIdentifier` method.

At this point I'm wondering whether I can use it at all to protect my queries? It is not of much use and tuning the quoted query like [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29668301/235671) suggests also doesn't seem to be right.

Is there anything I can do to protect the query and make it work and accept the name `[foo].[Bar]` without breaking it?

This is how I'm creating the query:

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
    "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = '{3}'{4}",
    ...,
    sanitizedTableName, // only [foo].[Bar] works -- [[foo]].[Bar]]] and [foo.Bar] fail
    ...,
    ...,
    ...);
```

Comment: Have you tried SqlParameter? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @buffjape I was going to use it for the `{3}` value later. Can I also use it to insert the table name? I have never tried to insert anything else. I guess that's the only usage I've ever seen... I'll try it and we'll see in a moment ;-)

Comment: You don't need the quotations if you use a parametrized query. Just add a parameter and specify the type of the column in the DB.

Comment: @Gnqz it's not the parameters that I'm having problems with (I'm going to use a parameter later). Currently it doesn't like the table name but I'll try to use them also for its name like buffjape suggested. I didn't know I could use them also for table names.

Comment: Try putting the table name in square brackets "[<tableName>]".

Comment: I've tried to use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` for the `{1}` parameter that I named `@TableName` but it complains _Must declare the table variable "@TableName"_. Apparently it cannot be used to insert table names.

Comment: The problem is, your table's name *isn't* `foo.bar`. You table's name is `bar` and its in the `foo` schema. Trying to sanitize it using functions that only expect to deal with a table name are going to fail because they're going to assume the `.` is part of the name and not a separator.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ok, that makes sense. Then I'll quote each part separately and concatenate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the name of the table is `bar`, not `foo.bar`. You're using a multi-part identifier - `foo` is the schema, and `bar` is the table name.

To get proper quoting, you need to quote each identifier separately:

```
QuoteIdentifier(schemaName) + "." + QuoteIdentifier(tableName)
```

The reason for this should be obvious - it's perfectly valid for a quoted identifier to use `.` as part of the name. That's kind of the whole point of having quoting in the first place.